# how to export table data using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

```
SELECT * FROM `tbProgramDetls`
WHERE dPrgrmdate
BETWEEN "2015-01-01"
AND "2015-01-08"
INTO OUTFILE 'directory' -> C:\myTable.csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

it shows error:-

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-> C:\myTable.csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES
>   TERMINATE' at line 5

how to execute this query.

Comment: Enclose C:myTable.csv path with '' ?

Comment: `INTO OUTFILE 'directory/myTable.csv'` or `INTO OUTFILE 'C:\myTable.csv'` - Read the FM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- the manual is tired of being called that way, please consider its feelings. :p

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbProgramDetls`
WHERE dPrgrmdate
BETWEEN "2015-01-01"
AND "2015-01-08"
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\myTable.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

---

Example as per the manual **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html**

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'a464cc2e'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Now shows this error

Comment: @user3717598 so you have an problme with your account.